# Combining files with same name in r and writing them into different files in R

Tags: r, csv

I have two folders with files having same names. e.g - FOLDER1 has a.csv, b.csv, c.csv and similarly FOLDER2 has a.csv, b.csv , c.csv

the files have different number of rows but the same number and name of columns

I want to combine files with the same name and write them into files with the name a.csv, b.csv c.csv.

This is just an example and I want to do it for 800-1000 files.

i tried

```
filenames <- list.files(c(filePathNew,filePath), pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
```

## has all the filenames from the two folders

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(filenames, basename(filenames)),function(x) do.call(rbind, 
lapply(x,function(y) read.csv(y, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, sep = ""))))

lapply(seq_along(lst1), function(i) write.csv(lst1[[i]], paste(filepath,names(lst1)[i], sep = "/"), row.names = FALSE, 
                        quote = FALSE))
```

but it shows the following error

```
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
Called from: stop("numbers of columns of arguments do not match")
```

Comment: What have you already tried yourself? Why did it not work?

Comment: Please look at the edited question

Comment: From the error message, it seems like at least one of the file pairs does not match up in the number of columns.  Try adding a `print` statement to print out the file pair before the `do.call` to see where this is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Again**

As you have now indicated you have Windows, you could use something like this saved as `CONCAT.BAT`

```
CD FOLDER1
MKDIR COMBINED
FOR %%G IN (*.CSV) DO COPY "%%G"+FOLDER2\"%%G" COMBINED\"%%G"
```

Then do

```
system("CONCAT.BAT", intern=FALSE)
```

**Updated Answer**

As you have more files than the 3 you initially suggested, you could use a script called `concat` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd FOLDER1
for f in *.csv; do cat "$f" FOLDER2/"$f" > "combined${f}"; done
```

and make it executable and run it with

```
system("chmod +x concat; ./concat", intern=FALSE)
```

**Original Answer**

If on Unix/Linux, try:

```
system("cat FOLDER1/a.csv FOLDER2/a.csv > aCombined.csv", intern=FALSE)
```

If on Windows, try:

```
system("copy FOLDER1\a.csv+FOLDER2\a.csv aCombined.csv", intern=FALSE)
```

Comment: I want to do it for a large number of files. is there another way?

Comment: What OS are you using?